# nginx accepts local network connection but not external, NATed

Tags: nginx, nat, ubuntu-16.04

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, with 2 network interfaces `***.20` and `***.30`

External connections to `80`,`443`,`25`,`995` are port-forwarded by the router to `***.30` interface.

### Synopsis:

nginx DOESN'T work (no connection accepted) when I try to open any page from outside.

### Checked:

1. nginx works(ie accepts connections, shows front page) when opening in browser `http://***.30/` and `https://***.30/`
2. works when I shut down nginx and run `sudo ncat -l ***.30 80` and `telnet mydomain.com 80` from outside: can see my typing on both sides. I think that wets the dns+port-forwarding+iptables.

### Questions:

What else could I check? Any pointers? Can I assume correct nginx config from the fact the page opens from local `***.30` interface ?

### Dumps, edited

Running nginx:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.13.6
built by gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
```

netstat:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Addr State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 ***.30:25     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      5150/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 ***.30:443    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      5150/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 ***.30:995    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      5150/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 ***.30:80     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      5150/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 ***.20:80     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      5150/nginx: master
```

iptables:

```
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere ***.30  tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere ***.30  tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere ***.30  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere ***.30  tcp dpt:pop3s
```

Comment: What you see when try to connect from outside?

Comment: I see nothing - `telnet` connection is not accepted and times out in ~30s.